# Jenkins maven build from stash issue

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket

While running a maven build from Jenkins using stash/bitbucket repo i am getting error. This is first time set of this project in stash/bitbucket and jenkins job as well

```
21:00:30 [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/project/folder && git push https://stash.xxx.com/scm/repo/folder refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop    
21:00:30 [INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/workspace/project/folder    
21:00:30 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------        
21:00:30 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE   
21:00:30 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------     
21:00:30 [INFO] Total time: 41.539 s   
21:00:30 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-01T16:00:30-04:00   
21:00:31 [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/179M   
21:00:31 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------    
21:00:31 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project ifaview: Unable to commit files   
21:00:31 [ERROR] Provider message:   
21:00:31 [ERROR] The git-push command failed.   
21:00:31 [ERROR] Command output:   
21:00:31 [ERROR] fatal: could not read Username for 'https://stash.xxxx.com': No such device or address
```

---

jenkins configuration @Source Code Management>Git>Repositories>

Repository URL=https://stash.xxx.com/scm/repo/folder.git
Credentials: jenkins_user/xxxxx

In stash repo settings for jenkins_user
Repository permission: read, write
Branch permission: Changes without a pull request  except jenkins_user
Pull request : merge and squash

Any one came across this problem, tried many other options as well...though no luck yet.

Comment: Can you compile the project locally on Jenkins machine ? Did you verify the settings.xml file ?